# How can i call python or java method from javaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, python

```
if (agentType == "IOS") {
    apiVersion = requestJsonObj.version;
    httpClient = {
        httpGet: function (requestUrl, user_agent) { 
            return httpRequest(requestUrl, user_agent);
        }
    }
}else if(agentType == "Android"){
    if(apiVersion>apiVersion_LastOld){
        httpClient = {
            httpGet: function (requestUrl, user_agent) {
                return result=com.esvideo.parse.util.ParseHttpUtil.httpGet(requestUrl, user_agent)+"";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

someone write this code in javascript but i don't know how  it works.

Comment: What is being returned ?

Comment: it can send http request and parse http response...

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: sorry... this is a javascript code, and it call a java method , but i don't know how it works ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no Python interpreter installed by default on an iOS device, and the Dalvik (not Java!) runtime on Android is not exposed to web pages.

Comment: sorry that i don't say clear about the problem . this is a javascript code, and it called java method( com.esvideo.parse.util.ParseHttpUtil.httpGet ), i want to know how it works

Comment: It doesn't work. At least, not in a normal Android web browser.